# Does DocuSign require a signers name and email, in order to generate a signing url?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a web app which I use to collect some information from a user (not name or email) and then plan on having them electronically sign a document via DocuSign immediately online (not via email).

**In order to get a signing url** (aka recipient view), it appears I have to provide a definition of a recipient.  Part of the definition of a "recipient" is a username and email address.  Is this true?

Does the DocuSign API/SDK require me to provide an end-user's (aka signer) name and email address?  It seems like the API/SDK will always return a validation error if I don't provide these things. What if I don't have that information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the signer's name and their client_user_id within *your* app. You also need to supply an email for them.

The client_user_id must be unique per signer.

If you have the signer's email, use it.

If you don't, use a unique email address that includes the client_user_id to guarantee uniqueness.  Eg noreply_{client_user_id} @your_company.com

**Added**

Re comments:

Yes, an email address is required by DocuSign to generate an embedded signing ceremony. But it is okay to fake one (that includes your app's client_user_id for the signer) if you don't, in fact, have the signer's email.

Re: Why is this the case? Because the email and name are used by DocuSign to index the "captive signer" (someone who signs your account's envelopes but doesn't have their own account with DocuSign). That's why a fake email must be unique to this person.

This technique of using name + email to identify people enables DocuSign to, for example, not require the signer to agree to the consumer agreement to use eSignatures on second and subsequent document signings with your account. -- This provides a better UX.

Since it is very common for web apps to know their user's email, this is usually not a problem. But if you don't know the signer's email, then everything works fine with a fake email as described above.

**Added more**

Re:

> please provide a source for DocuSign being Okay with fake email address in this case? I mean is it legal?

Currently this technique for providing a fake email address for embedded signing (when a real email address is not available), is not documented on the DocuSign web site. I will add it to the [embedded signing recipe](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/signing-from-your-app) when I revise it in 2017.

Re legality: the important issue is how your app *authenticates* the signer. Email is one way. Depending on the use case, email authentication may or may not provide a strong enough assurance to the relying party (the person who *receives* the signed document).

But we digress. Even if you do have a person's email address, it is common to authenticate the person *beyond* using their email. DocuSign has many different types of additional authentication built-in and easy to use including 2FA via SMS, pre-shared secret, in-person signing (which can include in-person verification of government ID), e-notary, digital certificates, telephone authentication, knowledge based authentication, and more. Most of these can be included with embedded signing if you wish.

Or your app (which is using embedded signing) can itself authenticate the person. When someone signed up for your app, did they have to first prove their identity? That was the authentication step. If no one else can log in as them, then they're still authenticated when you give them the embedded signing ceremony from DocuSign.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It sounds like you're saying that YES an email address is REQUIRED, and if I don't have one, fake one?

Comment: What's the purpose of requiring a signer's email address, if I intend to make the signer electronically sign immediatley on my web app?

Comment: @SteveKennedy -- I've added to my answer.

Comment: @LarryK Could you please provide a source for DocuSign being Okay with fake email address in this case? I mean is it legal?

Comment: @AmrFaisal See expanded answer.

Comment: @LarryK Thanks for the detailed answer.